# Apply opacity mask and annotate watermark with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to find a way to apply a watermark and opacity mask for an image using imagemagick. How do I do it?

**Source**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

Thank you all for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
convert a.png -brightness-contrast -60x-50  -pointsize 120 -gravity center -draw "fill white text 0,0 'SOLD'" b.png
```

Result:

[image: result]

Theoretically you could make the text bold by adding `-font "Arial-Bold"` or something like that, but it can't find the font on my system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works exactly the way I want :)